# Why is the date object in twig 1 day behind?

Tags: twig

I am using this in my template. The date of this post is 4/18/2018

**twig**

```
{% set today = "now"|date("m/d/Y") %}
{{ today }}  // 04/17/2018
```

I've tried setting the timezone explicitly as well.

```
{% set today = "now"|date("m/d/y", "America/Chicago") }}
{{ today }}  // 04/17/2018
```

If I try to get the hour:

```
{% set currentHour = today|date('H') %}
{{ currentHour }} // 00
```

Is there anything else that would be causing the date to be so far off?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong about the fact that the `date` filter return a `DateTime` object, in fact the `date` filter just returns a formatted string

```
{% set today = "now"|date("m/d/y", "America/Chicago") }}
{{ dump(today) }} {#  string(8) "04/19/18" #}
```

In order to solve your problem you would need to use the `date` function in `twig`

```
{% set today  = date("NOW",  "America/Chicago") %}
{{ dump(today) }}{# object(DateTime)#919 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-04-19 00:32:04" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "America/Chicago" } #}
{{ today | date('H', false) }} {# false = ignore default set timezone #}{# 07 #}
```

---

Small insight as why your hours as so *far* off

1. it's because the `date` filter will try and do it's best to convert any string in a valid `datetime` string, thus meaning, because `today` contains the string `04/17/2018`, that `twig` will convert the string to `04/17/2018 00:00:00` to create a valid `datetime` string
2. When omitting the timezone, `twig` will fall back to it's default timezone

---

In order to omit the `false` parameter in my example u would need to set the default the timezone in `twig`. This can be achieved with

```
$twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setTimezone('Europe/Paris');
```